# The "You can accept your own answer in <period>" alert is missing a period․

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, self-answer, notification-bar, grammar

When trying to accept your own answer too early, you get an alert like

> You can accept your own answer in 11 hours

According to the [Stacks design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods), it is missing a period; it's a full sentence after all.

Today I found another one:

> You may only fetch vote counts once every second

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Ironically, the [title I submitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/385036/1) had a period at the end, but it was stripped off by the system ...

Comment: Maybe that's the same filter at work. I've found you a consolation prize.

Comment: @Mast great - didn't know it doesn't apply to (other users'?) edits ...

Comment: It does. Try adding just a period in a title to any question and the edit will not even happen. However, there are many Unicode characters that *look* like a period without being one.

Comment: I love this question!